# Getting error while I was trying to configure protractor in my windows system

Tags: node.js, protractor, failed-installation

Below is the issue that I am facing while I tried to install Protractor,
Please help me as I need to install it by tomorrow for a project.

C:\Program Files\nodejs>npm install -g protractor
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "protractor"
npm ERR! node v4.6.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.9
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo

npm ERR! network getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND proxy.us.somecompany proxy.us.somecompany:8080
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "protractor"
npm ERR! node v4.6.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.9
npm ERR! path C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm-debug.log.3958700304
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm-debug.log.3958700304'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm-debug.log.3958700304']
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'open',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm-debug.log.3958700304' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm-debug.log

Comment: As it says in the error, "Please try running this command again as root/Administrator." ? It seems your node folder is in C:/Program Files, which is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Like @noKid mentioned, your nodejs is installed in the C:\Program Files\nodejs\ which is not ideal. To deal with your current issue, open an elevated CMD (open as an administrator) and run `npm install -g protractor` again.

Installing an node package with the `-g` flag means it will install globally.
This means you will be able to use the package you install from any location.

You are seeing this error because your nodejs installation is inside `C:\Program Files\nodejs\` and for an application to receive permissions to create additional resources (i.e. install protractor) it needs to be executed with administrative access.

Comment: Glad to hear it shashi, if the answer worked for you, please mark it as correct so other people with your issue can find the answer as well.